# quiero saber la cantidad de elementos no ocultos de una carpeta en java

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un programa el cual pueda contabilizar la cantidad de elementos seleccionados en una carpeta, esto usando JFileChooser.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JFileChooser selecto = (JFileChooser) e.getSource();
    String comand = e.getActionCommand();

    if (comand.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {

        File archivoSelect = selecto.getSelectedFile();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Guardado archivo " + archivoSelect.getName());

        System.out.println("Path: "+archivoSelect.getPath());
        System.out.println("Elementos de la carpeta: "+archivoSelect.list.length);

    }
}
```

Pero me he dado cuenta que ciertas carpetas contienen archivos ocultos creados por la PC como los archivos *thumbs.db* y esto provoca que el programa entregue un numero de archivos no coincidente con los que se ven a simple viste, así que mi duda sería el de como prevenir que el programa cuente los archivos ocultos.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa lo siguiente:

```
int cuenta=0;
JFileChooser selecto =new JFileChooser();
String comand = e.getActionCommand();
if (comand.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
   File rutaActual=selecto.getSelectedFile();
   File [] archivos=rutaActual.listFiles();
   for(int i=0;i<archivos.length ;i++){
       if(!archivos[i].isHidden()){
          cuenta++;
       }
   }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Guardado archivo "+ rutaActual.getName());
   System.out.println("Path: "+rutaActual.getPath());
   System.out.println("Elementos de la carpeta:+cuenta);
}
```